# Matplotlib: incorrect histograms

Tags: python, matplotlib

So I just learned about histograms on Khan Academy:

[image]

When I go plot something similar in Matplotlib, it is plotted differently. Why?

[image]

Shouldn't bins be completely filled? And since bin 5-6 has 3 counts (5, 6, 6), shouldn't it consists of a single bar of value 3? I'm confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `plt.hist()` creates 10 bins (or 11 edges). The default value is found [in the documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib-axes-axes-hist), and is taken from you rc parameter `rcParams["hist.bins"] = 10`.

So if you provide data in the range [1–6], `hist` will count the number of values in the bins: [1.–1.5), [1.5–2.), [2–2.5), [2.5–3.), [3–3.5), [3.5–4.), [4–4.5), [4.5–5.), [5.–5.5), [5.5–6.]. You can tell that that's the case by looking at the text output by `hist()` (in addition to the graph).

`hist()` [returns 3 objects](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.hist.html?highlight=hist#matplotlib-axes-axes-hist) when called:

- the height of each bar (that is the number of items in each bin), equivalent to the column "#" in that Khan video
- the edges of the bins, which is roughly equivalent to the column "Bucket" in the video
- a list of matplotlib objects that you can use to tweak their appearance when needed.

**In summary:**

If you want to have bars of width `1`, then you need to specify either the number of bins (5), or the edges of your bins.

These two calls provide the same result:

```
plt.hist(counts, bins=5)
plt.hist(counts, bins=[1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

**EDIT**
Here is a function that can help you see the "buckets" chosen by `hist`:

```
def hist_and_bins(x, ax=None, **kwargs):
    ax = ax or plt.gca()
    counts, edges, patches = ax.hist(x, **kwargs)
    bin_edges = [[a,b] for a,b in zip(edges, edges[1:])]
    ticks = np.mean(bin_edges, axis=1)
    tick_labels = ['[{}-{})'.format(l,r) for l,r in bin_edges]
    tick_labels[-1] = tick_labels[-1][:-1]+']' # last bin is a closed interval
    ax.set_xticks(ticks)
    ax.set_xticklabels(tick_labels)
    return counts, edges, patches, ax.get_xticks()



fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize=(9,3))
ax1.hist([1,2,3,4,5,6,6])
hist_and_bins([1,2,3,4,5,6,6], ax=ax2)
hist_and_bins([1,2,3,4,5,6,6], ax=ax3, bins=5, ec='w')
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

[image]

Comment: If so, why isn't edge 1.5 or 2.5 labelled?

Comment: What do you mean "labelled"? They are returned by the function

Comment: You see on my graph, the labels on the x-axis are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6. If the bins edges are in fact 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, ..., why do only the integers 1, 2, 3, 4,... get labels and not 1.5, 2.5, ...?

Comment: The ticks on the x-axis are chosen automatically by matllotlib, they do not necessarily reflect the edges of the bins. If you want to have the actual edges shown on the x-axis, then you have to request that. Look for `plt.xticks` or this website for examples

Comment: @NoName I was thinking about your question earlier and though it would be nice to have a little function that prints the bins under each bar. I've added it to my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: Nice! Now I see why they decided to not to label bins by default, but instead the x-axis. It gets congested fast and totally not scalable!